# Don't call second click event after first has returned false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue with a pop-up menu. I basically have 2 click events, one is for opening a menu, which returns `false` if a particular button is clicked and the other click event is on the `document` and meant to close the menu if someone clicks anywhere on the page but the menu.

In below example, I'm not expecting to see `click on document` in the console, but I do. What am I doing wrong?

```
$('#content .addOptions').live("click",function(){
  console.log("click on addoptions")

    return false;
});


$(document).click(function () {
  console.log("click on document")

});
```

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/FMBuc/ ( I didn't change anything )

Comment: Exactly like that. I have done it before, but for some reason this script is disagreeing.

Comment: @Lokase, is this going to fix the issue?

Comment: Not sure, but "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated."

Comment: I'm working on someone else code and don't want to rewrite the full JS, so for now, `live` it is.

Comment: I have just tested Kevin's Fiddle using the jQuery version from the system, 1.6.4. and it doesn't work in that version, but it does in jQuery 1.7+

Comment: @Richard In jQuery 1.7+, I believe `.live()` actually calls `.on()`, which is probably why it works. Try using `.delegate()` instead, since `.on()` wasn't in the version of jQuery you're using.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist The same thing happens with delegate in 1.6.4, it's more than likely a bug that was fixed in a later version, such as 1.7.2

Comment: Thanks Anthony, for now I have upgraded to 1.7.2 (best going forward). For some reason 1.8 broke the code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prevent the bubbling of the click event up to the document level, as you are indeed clicking on both the menu and the document which contains it. So do this:

```
$('#content .addOptions').on("click",function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log("click on addoptions")

    return false;
});
```

Note also the change to using `on` method instead of `live`.

Comment: Returning false with `return false` in a jQuery bound event handler is the same as doing both `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()`. Additionally, that flavour of `.on()` isn't equivalent to the use of `.live()` in the question.

Comment: I have found out that the issue appears in my JQ version 1.6.4. but not in later versions, so I'll try to upgrade. Thanks!